# regex_substr to split by delimiter

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to do a simple thing:

My input string is something like '001/002' ( This is not fixed length, but two strings/numbers separated by delimiter '/')

I need to get the first part as '001' and second as '002'

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fde49/5

Without using connect by prior and in same row as two columns.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fde49/6

Comment: Thanks, "Eat A peach", It does the job!